# Scrapy Parse table and skip table rows using their class names

Tags: python, dynamic, web-scraping, scrapy

```
import scrapy
from mystocks.items import MystocksItem
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import datetime

class Synergyspider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "synergyspider"
    allowed_domains = ["http://live.mystocks.co.ke/price_list/"]


    def parse(self, response):

        sel = Selector(response)


        head = sel.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/h2')
        rows_r1 = sel.xpath('//tr[@class = "row r1"]')



        items = []



        for row in rows_r1:

            item = MystocksItem()
            item['date'] = head.xpath('text()').extract()[0]
            item['code'] = rows_r1.xpath('./td[1]/a/text()').extract()[0]
            item['name'] = rows_r1.xpath('./td[2]/text()').extract()[0]
            item['last12_low'] = rows_r1.xpath('./td[3]/text()').extract()[0]
            item['last12_high'] = rows_r1.xpath('./td[4]/text()').extract()[0]
            #item['day_low'] = rows_r1.xpath('./td[5]/text()').extractf()[0]
            item['day_high'] = rows_r1.xpath('./td[6]/text()').extract()[0]
            item['price'] = rows_r1.xpath('./td[7]/text()').extract()[0]
            item['previous'] = rows_r1.xpath('./td[8]/text()').extract()[0]
            item['change'] = rows_r1.xpath('./td[9]/text()').extract()[0]
            item['percentChange'] = rows_r1.xpath('./td[10]/text()').extract()[0]
            item['volume'] = rows_r1.xpath('./td[12]/text()').extract()[0]
            item['adjustedPrice'] = rows_r1.xpath('./td[13]/text()').extract()[0]

            items.append(item)


        return items
```

---

The url I was trying to parse is http://live.mystocks.co.ke/price_list/20140402
I want to iterate over the rows with classes "row r1" and "row r0" but skip the rows with class "row".

Comment: my output basically loops over the very first row   [synergyspider] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://live.mystocks.co.ke/price_list/20140402>
 {'adjustedPrice': u'-',
  'change': u'-',
  'code': u'EGAD',
  'date': u'Price list and trading summary for Wednesday, April 02, 2014',
  'day_high': u'29.00',
  'last12_high': u'100.00',
  'last12_low': u'30.00',
  'name': u'Eaagads',
  'percentChange': u'-',
  'previous': u'29.00',
  'price': u'29.00',
  'volume': u'-'}

Answer (score 0):

found out i was loping on the wrong variable, loop on row not row_r1